# How CompletableFuture returns result to client in play framework

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I am using this code:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
    return computerRepository.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).thenApplyAsync(list -> {
        // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
        return ok(views.html.list.render(list, sortBy, order, filter));
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

Since, it is written thenApplyAsync, how does the client receives this result. Doesn't the client returns as soon as new thread is spawned off.

Comment: Who is “the client” in the context of your question? Your method returns immediately, but that doesn’t say anything about the the caller. The caller may wait for the completion or may chain another action, like “send reponse”.

Comment: The caller is front-end from where the request came

Comment: The caller here is Play Framework actually.

Comment: "Doesn't the client returns as soon as new thread is spawned off" - in Play framework, no, it doesn't.